# Retrofit returns list with elements who have empty values

Tags: android, api, kotlin

Hi i am using the https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/ Api and for some reason when i do a top movies request retrofit returns a normal list of movies.

```
@GET("/movies/popular")
fun getMovies(@Query("page") pageNo: Int, @Query("limit") limit: Int): Flowable<List<Movie>>
```

But when i use the search

```
 @GET("/search/{id_type}")
fun getMoviesForQuery(@Path("id_type") type: String,
                    @Query("query") query: String,
                    @Query("page") pageNo: Int?,
                    @Query("limit") limit: Int?): Flowable<List<Movie>>
```

it returns a list of movies with null values. This is how i use retrofit:

```
 if (query == "") {
            compositeDisposable.add(moveApi.getMovies(pageNumber, params.requestedLoadSize).subscribe { movies ->
                callback.onResult(movies)
            })
        } else {
            compositeDisposable.add(
                    moveApi.getMoviesForQuery(movieType, query, ++pageNumber,
                            params.requestedLoadSize).subscribe { movies ->
                        callback.onResult(movies)
                    })
        }
```

Am i doing something wrong or is the api broken.

**EDIT**: Worth noting is that when you receive the searched movies altough nulls the size is different for the different search. For example if i make a request with "gg" i receive 17 results but when i do a with a different string for example "gggg" i recive 0 results. Which in my opinion means that the requests are made properly its just that the data is lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the mistake was mine.The search call to the api returns a different kind of JSON model so when the parsing was done my model did not match the other one.